# Using dynamic html in javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

in my work, there is a phone button that when user clicks on it, few html elements are replaced there. To open these html elements, i used phoneOpenEditor function. In the new html elements, there is a cancel button that when user clicks on it, another html elements should be loaded. To use this button, i use closeEditor functon.

here is the constructor:

```
class BE_ContactEditor {
initialization

constructor() {
this.body = $(".contact-block-header");
this.phone = this.body.find(".js-phone");
this.events();
```

}

and here is the event part, in the event part:

```
events(){

this.phone.on("click",this.phoneOpenEditor.bind(this));


//it is the cancel button
this.phone.on('click', '.fa-minus-circle', this.closeEditor.bind(this));
}
```

here is the openEditor function that can be used with phone button:

```
phoneOpenEditor(e){
this.html = this.phone.html();
this.phone.html(`
  <div class="icon negative big toleft" id="cancel-btn"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></div>
  `)
}
```

here is the closeEditor function that can be used with cancel button:

```
closeEditor(){
 this.html = this.phone.html();
 this.phone.html(`
   <div class="page-subtitle-backend narow cover selectable js-phone" data-type"phone"><div class="icon add big"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></div> add Phone</div>
   `)
 }
```

The problem is, the html elements inside the closeEditor function is not loaded after clicking on the cancel button.

I really will be appreciated if anyone can help me on this. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Provide a working example please.

Comment: Probably just an event bubble issue, since you're capturing "click" at the `phone` level and at the `'.fa-minus-circle'`, but not stopping propagation. so it runs `closeEditor`, then immediately `phoneOpenEditor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add an event object to your `closeEditor` method as an argument and call this method of the event object. `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`

That should work. Here is the updated code,

```
closeEditor(e){
 e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 this.html = this.phone.html();
 this.phone.html(`
   <div class="page-subtitle-backend narow cover selectable js-phone" data-type"phone"><div class="icon add big"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></div> add Phone</div>
   `)
 }
```

Hope this helps.